# A delete key doesn't work in a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 (inputs 0x007F instead)

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, ibus

After a complete, fresh reinstall of my computer from 18.04 to 20.04, I found that the delete key isn't *deleting* the next character but instead only *inputting* the `0x007F` Unicode Delete character.

This happens in any input field (although some input fields don't show the `0x07F` character).

**Any ideas on what might be interfering with the normal Delete behaviour?**

---

*Some further hints and details:*

1. Everything worked on the previous 18.04 Ubuntu
2. Although it was a fresh install, I ran an [installation script](https://www.codepile.net/pile/zbEVxo9X) installing some programs that might have interfered with the default behaviour. (I didn't manage to notice whether it works or not right after the fresh install)
3. Deleting files in Nautilus works
4. Switching the keyboard input to Japanese(Mozc), the Delete key works normally there.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking in on the question. Are you talking about the "installation script"? That's just some of the programs I've installed, most of them are irrelevant to this, I just thought someone might identify one of those programs as capable of changing the behaviour of the keyboard, although none of them shouldn't.